# SQL Server: Permissions on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I find out what kind of roles have what kind of permissions on a given table in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get all permissions granted in the database and filter out for your table:

```
select permission_name, state, pr.name
from sys.database_permissions pe
join sys.database_principals pr on pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
where pe.class = 1 
    and pe.major_id = object_id('<table_name>')
    and pe.minor_id = 0;
```

In addition you need to add the built in role permissions (db_owner, db_datareader, db_datawriter etc). Objects may also be accessed through [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx).

You can always find out your own effective permission on any object by using [`fn_my_permissions('table_name', 'OBJECT')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx)

Comment: the query works fine. A 'blank row' (an empty result set) is a valid response. Is actually the expected result for a table on which no explicit grants were issued.

Comment: So... if I get a blank row... how do I know ... who has what permissions on this table? Thanks..

Comment: There are implicit permissions, the ones derived from the fixed roles: db_owner members have all permissions, db_datareader members can select from it, db_datawriter member can update it etc etc. And all other permissions that are derived from ownership chaining. Read the link in the post.

Comment: Try granting an explicit right, like `GRANT SELECT ON <table> TO guest` and then run again the query to see the non-implicit permission grant.