# Check permission to a table

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-permissions

I am currently making a vb.net program that needs to check permissions on a table (if the table does not exsist, then the permission on the database, if the database does not exsist, then the permission to the sql server)

is there a way to check thouse permissions, and how?

- how do i check the permissions on the table "testdb.testtable" for
  the user "testuser"
- how do i check the permissions on the database    "testdb" for the
  user "testuser"
- how do i check the permissions on    the server for user "testuser"

i've been searching on google, but the result i got, was a 2 pages long sql script.

Comment: I think another question here is "why"? Do you need to do something specific if you don't have permissions? If all you need to do is display an appropriate error, then just try to do whatever it is you need to do with the `testdb.testtable` table, and SQL will throw an error, and an accurate error message and error numbers (that you can switch() over), with the problem.

Comment: my idea was to check if the table exsisted, if it did, and you had INSERT permission, start inserting new rows.

however if the table did not exsist, then create the table, if user had permission to alter a database. if the database did not exsist, then create the database, if the user had permissions to create a new database.

this was mostly to add this as a initial try, before starting to post data, to prevent data loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would push responsibility of creating the database onto the end-user - and allow the user to specify that database; it may be valid for an installer to create the database, but again it should also accept one already created where the name has been supplied by the end user. You do not want to assume a database name as if the end-user already has a database created with that name, you will be in direct conflict with it.

That said, permissions are stored in [`sys.database_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) which outline a user's permissions in the database this is queried from and [`sys.server_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186260.aspx) to find out if they have the ability to create a database.

Helpfully though SQL Server have a function that wraps up querying permissions - the [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx) function comes in handy here, for example:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'CREATE TABLE')
```

...will look to see if the current user has the ability to 'CREATE TABLE' in the named database, whilst

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'CREATE ANY DATABASE')
```

...will tell you if the current user can create databases. The names of the permissions are those that you'd pass through to `GRANT`. Consult the docs for more information and examples.

Comment: this looks like the same conclusion i came up to. the reason i need to log the database user's permissions, is becasue its a windows service i made, and if it fails, i the end user needs to know in details what whent wrong, to easen the frustration.

thanks for examples

Answer (score 1):

I also was able to assemble another SQL Query.. however this will return an error, if the user does not have access to the database.

```
SELECT pe.*,object_name(pe.major_id), pr1.name as Grantee, pr2.name as Grantor, pr1.create_date,pr1.default_schema_name  from sys.database_permissions as pe
join sys.database_principals as pr1 on pe.grantee_principal_id = pr1.principal_id 
join sys.database_principals as pr2 on pe.grantor_principal_id = pr2.principal_id
where pr1.name = CURRENT_USER 
go
```

by adding "use ReplaceWithNameOfDatabase"

the query will ask up against that database.

i've never really worked with MSSQL before, only MYSQL, and it seems there is alot of big diffrences in how userlogin data is stored.

i found this [SQL Server: Permissions on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049085/sql-server-permissions-on-table)
worked for me, with a little modification