# Two connections cannot be opened for an application role user

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I have set an application role for a database in SQL Server, so that other than my application nothing can access that database.
But the problem is when I am trying to open two record-sets in same method, it throws an error that permission is not there for the second statement.

***Example code*** :

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "Select * from Table1", Connection

rs2.Open "Select * from Table2", Connection

rs.Close

rs2.Close
```

When it is executing the second query, throws an error:

> "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Table2', database 'Dat1', schema 'dbo'. (Error Number -2147217911)"

Comment: Please help me overcome this error.

Comment: You can [check all permissions over `Table2`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3049085/4519059) ;).

Comment: In application i find such scenarios in many places. So it is not that feasible to check permissions on all those tables :(